# Cython : mitr argument of scipy.optimize.cython_optimize.brentq function - What is this argument used for?

Tags: python, scipy, arguments, cython, scipy-optimize

`mitr` argument is a argument of the function scipy.optimize.cython_optimize.brentq that is set to 10 on the reference guide https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.cython_optimize.html.
How the brentq function uses this argument? Could not find any explanation about it.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [docs for `brentq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html#scipy.optimize.brentq) and counting the arguments?

Comment: Yes, it has 9 arguments, and the closest one is maxiter, but I'm not sure if they are related to the same thing.

Comment: I would be pretty confident that it's maxiter. But it isn't documented very well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `mitr` in [`scipy.optimize.cython_optimize` documentation examples](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.cython_optimize.html) corresponds to `maxiter` in `brentq`, `bisect`, `ridder`, *etc*. I agree it's confusing, and `maxiter` would've been a better choice for consistency, but it's only an example, perhaps it can still be updated. The underlying C & Cython functions use `iter` which is a keyword in Python. You will find the [Cython headers in `cython_optimize/_zeros.pxd`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/cython_optimize/_zeros.pxd) and the zero function signatures in [the zeros header `scipy/optimize/zeros.h`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/Zeros/zeros.h). The order of arguments are almost the same. Sorry